# Limit sessions number concurrent per account user devise, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Using Rails 4.0 and ruby 2.1.0

I'm working on a project that will be subscription based and the accounts need to have a limit of concurrent sessions per user. For example, normal user 1 concurrent session per account, medium user - 3 concurrent sessions per account and premium user 10 concurrent sessions per account.

I have checked every page of google, stackoverflow, differents gems like devise:timeoutable or devise_session_limit gem. I have tried with a field called connections which is 1, 3 or 10 depending on user. If user login, decrement -1 the connections field, if user logout then increment +1 connectios field. The thing or problem is when the user keep open the session and leave, then never will increment +1.

Any suggestions?? I am working on this task almost 3 days and I cannot get it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution you tried with the incrementing/decrementing the connections sounds good but it needs to be used along with the timeoutable gem so that the sessions that are left open can be automatically timed out and the connections incremented.

Comment: Yes, I tried do that, but I cannot find de solution to put it together. The thing is how I can controll when timeout is closing the session. I searched something like callbacks, in this way: before timeout close session, but I couldn't find something.
Thanks diego!

Comment: I was looking around this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088501/detect-when-a-devise-session-expires) , but I didn't work for me. I don't know how I can rewrite this module, do you?

Comment: I have same problem, I tried adding session_limit and session_count to user table. It works fine when user logs out and timeout  logout occurs.  When user closes  the browser without logging out then session_count  persists and I get message called session limit reached

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into devise and as long as you have the :timeoutable module you can check that a user has been timed out and run whatever code you like. See this warden hook for reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb

The important part of that code is the check for `record.timedout?`. If that's true, run your connections increment code.

To be specific, write a `config/initializers/connections_updater.rb` file with this (similar to above linked code it is a warden hook):

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |record, warden, options|
  scope = options[:scope]
  env   = warden.request.env

  if record && record.respond_to?(:timedout?) && warden.authenticated?(scope) && options[:store] != false
    last_request_at = warden.session(scope)['last_request_at']

    if last_request_at.is_a? Integer
      last_request_at = Time.at(last_request_at).utc
    elsif last_request_at.is_a? String
      last_request_at = Time.parse(last_request_at)
    end

    proxy = Devise::Hooks::Proxy.new(warden)

    if record.timedout?(last_request_at) && !env['devise.skip_timeout']
      # write this method to do what you need when the session times out
      record.increment_connections_count! # Note: record is the user model

      Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? proxy.sign_out : proxy.sign_out(scope)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks pretty good!! I tried in your way, but I got this error:

`NameError in DeviseInvitable::SessionsController#create`
`uninitialized constant Devise::Hooks`

I tried to solve myself, but I couldn't. What I missing??
Thanks Diego again!!