# Execute some code when a session timeout using devise is detected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for authentication. When we enable the timeoutable module as follows, session timeout feature is enabled.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable
end
```

I am writing a simple multiplayer rooms logic so i have a room list that shows a list of rooms and also users currently residing in each room. My goal is as soon as a session for some user is expired because of inactivity, the event should be detected and a code to clear the user from the room should be executed. In short i am wondering whether it is possible to detect session timeout and execute  code when that happens?

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when a devise session expires](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088501/detect-when-a-devise-session-expires)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your best bet would be to look at this question:

[Detect when a devise session expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088501/detect-when-a-devise-session-expires)

Where they are overriding the `timeoutable` method and implementing their own code:

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Timeoutable
      def timedout?(last_access)
        #  your custom code goes into this method
        return false if remember_exists_and_not_expired?
        !timeout_in.nil? && last_access && last_access <= timeout_in.ago
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks but where should this code reside i.e which file? thanks!